# How to return a default value from a Map?

Tags: javascript

Using the ES6 Proxy object it is possible to return a default value when a property does not exist in a plain object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

How to do this with a Map? I have tried the following code but the default value is always returned:

```
var map = new Map ([
    [1,  'foo'],  // default
    [2,  'bar'],
    [3,  'baz'],
]);

var mapProxy = new Proxy(map, {
    get: function(target, id) {
        return target.has(id) ? target.get(id) : target.get(1);
    },
});

console.log( mapProxy[3] );  // foo
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's because your map keys are numbers, but the proxy property name is always a string. You would need to cast `id` to a number first.

#### Working Example (requires modern JS engine):

```js
var map = new Map ([
    [1,  'foo'],  // default
    [2,  'bar'],
    [3,  'baz'],
]);

var mapProxy = new Proxy(map, {
    get: function(target, id) {
        // Cast id to number:
        id = +id;
        return target.has(id) ? target.get(id) : target.get(1);
    },
});

console.log( mapProxy[3] ); // baz
console.log( mapProxy[10] ); // foo
```

Answer (score 3):

A nice way of writing this is:

```
const map = new Map ([
    [1,  'foo'],  // default
    [2,  'bar'],
    [3,  'baz'],
]);

const get = (id) => map.get(id) ?? map.get(3);  // 3 as default
console.log(get(1));  // Returns 'foo' as expected
console.log(get(42));  // Defaults to 'baz'
```

Comment: I would prefer the `??` operator here, to avoid overriding keys such as `0` or the empty string.

Comment: Thanks @TedBrownlow. Updated according to your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

In Scala, maps are monads with `getOrElse` method. If monad (a container) contains no value, its `get` method fails with exception but getOrElse allows the user to write infallible code

```
Map.prototype.getOrElse = function(key, value) {
  return this.has(key) ? this.get(key) : value
}

var map = new Map ([[1,  'foo'],  [2,  'bar'], [3,  'baz']]); 
[map.get(1), map.getOrElse(10, 11)]; // gives 11
```

Another option is to expand your maps `withDefaultValue` method

```
//a copy of map will have a default value in its get method
Map.prototype.withDefaultValue = function(defaultValue) {
  const result = new Map([...this.entries()]); 
  const getWas = result.get; result.get = (key) => 
    result.has(key) ? getWas.call(this, key) : defaultValue; 
  return result
}
map.withDefaultValue(12).get(10) // gives 12
```

It is the way it is done in Scala. Or, at least, looks that way.